# Error with binding variables

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm getting an error in a prepared statement I am writing...

```
 Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables on line 33. Create Topic Insert bind_param() failed:
```

The only thing I can think of is because of the `NOW()` fields, but I thought it was not needed to set a variable for that?

Is there something I am clearly missing in this or what could be causing this error?

```
//Prepared INSERT stmt for the forum topic
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO forum_topics (`category_id`, `topic_title`, `topic_creator`, `topic_date`, `topic_reply_date`) 
    VALUES(?, ?, ?, NOW(), NOW())");
    if ( !$stmt || $con->error ) {
        die('Create Topic Insert prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt->bind_param('sssii', $cid, $title, $creator)) {
        die('Create Topic Insert bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt->execute()) {
        die('Create Topic Insert execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
```

Comment: U are binding 3 ... sss

Answer (score 0):

> mysqli_stmt::bind_param -- mysqli_stmt_bind_param — Binds variables to a prepared statement as parameters

So in your bind_param, you need insert 5 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. I was trying to bind the `NOW()` fields. I changed the code line to..

```
  if(!$stmt->bind_param('sssii', $cid, $title, $creator)) {
```

and it works perfectly now.